# Div over an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I 've been trying several things but I am not able to set a div over an iframe which displays fullscreen, here's the iframe:

```
<iframe src="//domain.com" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; h 
height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
```

I would like to show a div fixed on right corner bottom, how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: And what does this look like? Need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: why is your z-index for the iFrame so high if you want to display a div above of it you'll need to have it on a higher z-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that youre `<iframe>` is a direct child of page's `<body>`.
You can easily achieve your goal by settings the right `right`, `bottom` and `z-index` properties of your corner div.

Don't forget that the `z-index` property controls how the elements are placed on the z axis ([look at mdn description for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)).

Here is an exemple of what it can looks like :

```css
#iframe {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

#corner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
  <div id="corner">I'm in right bottom corner !</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```css
.right-bottom-corner {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="//domain.com" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%;height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow: hidden; z-index:1;"></iframe>
 <div class="right-bottom-corner"></div>
```